# What are the requirements to test a website using jquery.get()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a simple website.  It has to search quite a few text files in different sub-folders.  The rest of the page uses jquery, so I would like to use it for this also.  The function I am looking at is **.get()** for downloading the files.  So my main question is, can I test this on my local computer (Ubuntu Linux) or do I have to have it uploaded to a server?

Also, if there's a better way to go about this, that would be nice to know.  However, I'm more worried about getting it working.

Thanks,
Frankie

PS: Heres the JS/jQuery code for downloading the files to an array.

```
    g_lists = new Array();
    $(":checkbox").each(function(i){
        if ($(this).attr("name") != "0")
        {
            var path = "../" + $(this).attr("name") + ".txt";
            $("#bot").append("<br />" + path); // debug
            $.get(path, function(data){
            g_lists[i] = data;
            $("#bot").html(data);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            g_lists[i] = "";
        }
    });
```

Edit: Just a note about the path variable.  I think it's correct, but I'm not 100% sure.  I'm new to web development.  Here's some examples it produces and the directory tree of the site.  Maybe it will help, can't hurt.

```
.
├── include
│   ├── jquery.js
│   └── load.js
├── index.xhtml
├── style.css
└── txt    
     └── Scripting_Tools
        ├── Editors.txt
        └── Other.txt
```

Examples of path:

```
../txt/Scripting_Tools/Editors.txt
../txt/Scripting_Tools/Other.txt
```

Well I'm a new user, so I can't "answer" my own question, so I'll just post it here:

After asking for help on a IRC chat channel specific to jQuery, I was told I could use this on a local host.  To do this I installed Apache web server, and copied my site into it's directory.  More information on setting it up can be found here: http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_debian_lamp_server

Then to run the site I navigated my browser to "localhost" and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) desktop app and wrap up your JS in there. Titanium seems to eliminate the cross-domain scripting issues when running JS from inside a packaged app.